# Get ID from rows with repeated values on two colums to update them later

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
ID, campaign, merchant,date.
```

I need to know what rows are repeated, which means, which have the same campaign with the same merchant, example:

```
ID, campaign, merchant, date
1, "hello", 260, 01/01/21
2, "hello", 260, 01/01/21
```

I can do this with this:

```
select campaign, merchant, count(*)
from public.my_table
group by campaign, merchant
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That's ok, but I haven't found the way to change these repeated "campaign" to "hello day/month/year hour:minute:seconds" with this last query.

so what i want is to change the repeated campaigns (for the same merchant) like this:

```
ID, campaign, merchant, date
1, "hello 01/01/2021 02:22:22", 260
2, "hello 01/01/2021 02:22:32", 260
```

Its been hours but no luck yet, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think I have found a solution minutes later I wrote the post:

```
UPDATE public.my_table
SET campaign =  campaign || date
where id in (
SELECT id FROM
  (SELECT *, count(*)
  OVER
    (PARTITION BY
      campaign,
      merchant
    ) AS count
  FROM public.my_table) tableWithCount
  WHERE tableWithCount.count > 1
)
```